# mouse movement leaves trails of th image

Tags: c#, winforms

i have made a space invader game. at first the game ran slow whenever i moved the mouse because i had a mouse move event, so someone told me that it was my invalidate method. i changed it accordingly and the game speed is better. but it now does not clear the older image. it leaves a trail of images.

Please help!

**Mouse_move event**

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Dispose();
        objsp.gsPos = new Point(MousePosition.X / 2 - 10, MousePosition.Y / 2 - 15);
        UpdatePosition(objsp.gsPos.X, objsp.gsPos.Y, objsp.gsImage);
    }
```

**UpdatePosition method that is being called**

```
    private void UpdatePosition(int dx, int dy, Image img)
    {            
        Point newPos = new Point(objsp.gsPos.X + dx, objsp.gsPos.Y + dy);

        //dont go out of window boundary
        newPos.X = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ClientSize.Width - img.Width, newPos.X));
        newPos.Y = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ClientSize.Height - img.Height, newPos.Y));

        if (newPos != objsp.gsPos)
        {
            objsp.gsPos = newPos;
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(objsp.gsPos, img.Size);
            Invalidate(rc);               
        }
    }
```

**Form Load output[image]**

**Once mouse is moved output**

[image]

Comment: I bet your paint handler is not redrawing what it is being asked to redraw

Comment: **private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {            
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(objsp.gsImage, objsp.gsPos.X, objsp.gsPos.Y, objsp.gsImage.Width, objsp.gsImage.Height);                        
        }**

Comment: That looks like you aren't updating the full region

Answer (score 1):

In `UpdatePosition` invalidate both current and previous mouse position.

Comment: **private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {            
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(objsp.gsImage, objsp.gsPos.X, objsp.gsPos.Y, objsp.gsImage.Width, objsp.gsImage.Height);                        
        }** I've noticed that when at least 10 invaders are killed the game moves normal... now in puzzled.

Comment: Most likely because less to draw means faster processing.  Each paint comes quicker before the sprite has moved far.  MagnatLU's solution will address both cases.